# Enter stream() or map() in Eclipse without using Arrow keys

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-2020-03

I am using Eclipse 2020-03.

What annoys me:

When I have some list `someList` and I type:

```
someList.stream
```

then `parallelStream()` is the highest showing element in the autocomplete. So when I enter `(`, I see

```
someList.parallelStream()
```

The only way to avoid this (I have found so far) is to input `stream` and then hit the down arrow key to choose `stream()` from the list.

The same happens with `.map` which is always replaced by `.flatMap()`.

I never use `parallelStream` or `flatMap` so I find this not very useful.

Is there some way to enter these things without using the arrow keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually yes. Open `Window -> Preferences`, you can find Context Assist under `Java -> Content Assist`.
Uncheck the `Show substring matches`, then it's gonna show what exactly matches your typing.